# Does a capacitor in an inverting op-amp make a difference?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, inverting-amplifier

Just a quick question, does a capacitor in an inverting op-amp make a difference to the transfer function? Or, are just the resistors taken into consideration?

Non-Inverting op-amp:

\$ \dfrac{R1 + R2}{R1} \cdot V_{in} \$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbj4uo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Inverting op-Amp:

\$ - \dfrac{R2}{R1} \cdot V_{in} \$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRY793.png)</sup>

In both of the above equations, capacitance is not a factor, yet in a number of circuits, capacitors are present as voltage regulators.

Comment: Please clarify which position the capacitors are in that you are talking about. Across supply rails, or in series or parallel with R1 or R2?

Comment: @IllBeBack Welcome to EE.SE. It's standard practice here to wait at least a day before accepting an answer to a question, to encourage more answers and traffic. You can upvote and downvote to your heart's content.

Comment: The capacitors don't make a difference, because they aren't there. When you actually add them to the schematic, then they make a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gains of the two op-amp circuits you refer to are DC gains and, in simple circuit configurations apply across a range of frequencies up to a certain "limit".

The "limit" is usually (but not exclusively) the point where the op-amp can no longer sustain the desired gain and this may be due to parasitic capacitance on the circuit board, intentionally placed caps or internal capacitors within the op-amp.

This means the formula for the op-amp's gain is modified by a capacitor across R2 - this is an approximation but gives reasonable results. There are other places caps have an effect but normally, it's the feedback components that are generally affected first.

So, more realistically, any op-amp gain formula of the type you mentioned only holds true for DC and low/medium frequencies and if you were to be more accurate, the formulas would include effects of capacitance and, "normally" with op-amps this is the addition of a capacitor across R2.

At certain "higher" frequencies this capacitance will have the same magnitude of impedance as R2 and this is often referred to as the 3dB point of the circuit - this is the point at which the amplifier's gain falls to about 70% of what it was at much lower frequencies.

Capacitors are also commonly placed in series with R1 in order to minimize low frequency or DC effects. In this situation there is another 3dB point at a low frequency and that is when the impedance of the cap is the same magnitude as R1. As frequency lowers the cap becomes dominant and reduces the gain even more until at DC the op-amp has no gain.

[image]

The above diagrams are for inverting op-amp configurations.

Caps used intentionally in the described situations give the op-amp circuit the ability to pass a range of frequencies whilst attenuating others above and below the range - they are called band-pass circuits. If there is no cap in series with R1 but there is a cap in parallel with R2 this is a low-pass filter.

Comment: So would I change the formula to include the capacitance, or just strike it out as it doesn't affect it? If I need to include capacitance in the transfer function, what would it be? (C(R2)/R1?)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so soon by the way, I really appreciate your help

Comment: It's not as simple as that. Try looking at this page http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/opamp/node3.html - you need to understand the formula for a caps impedance and this link should provide some help - there is a frequency dependent term that I'll try and add to the diagram I've shown

Comment: what if there is no resistor but a single capacitor only? how to calculate the gain?