# voltage transfer ratio

Tags: voltage, transfer-function, ratio

[image]

I painted the currents, used the first Kirchhoff's law and got the expression:

[image]

Next, I need to find the voltage transfer coefficient **(Ku)**, that is, the ratio of the output voltage to the input voltage, but I do not quite understand how to do this due to the fact that there is *dU(out)* and just *U(out)*

Comment: Are you familiar with the Laplace transform? If not, select a single frequency for analysis, say, \$\sin(\omega t)\$, express the derivative of that in terms of the signal itself so that only the signal appears in the expression. e.g. \$\frac{d\sin(\omega t)}{dt}= \omega \cdot \sin(\omega t + \pi/2)\$ So for a sinusoidal signal \$|dU| = |\omega U|\$.

Comment: Is DA1 an op amp? See this answer for effect of the capacitor: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/68710/95488

Comment: Yes, it is an op amp

Comment: DC gain is -R2/R1 and AC gain reduces to -3dB when ZC(f)=R2

Comment: Your formula with time-derivatives is in the 'time domain' (signals are described as varying in time). Transfer functions (or coefficients if you prefer that term) are in the 'frequency domain' (signal amplitudes are a function of frequency). That's the reason for AJN's advice.

Comment: however, I don't understand how to get from this formula Uout/Uin